# RestKit Object mapping issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have this JSON response that I can't figure out how to map. It looks like this:

```
{
  "responseError": null,
  "displayMenuList": {
    "MenuList": [
      {
        "ID": "3223",
        "Name": "Main",
        "AddressURL": "www.mysite.com",
        "DisplayType": "True",
        "ImageURL": "main.png",
        "NotSplitBUser": "True",
        "ParentCategoryId": "3223",
        "PrivateUser": "True",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "SplitBUser": "True",
        "TargetURL": "_self"
      },
      {
        "ID": "3307",
        "Name": "Contact",
        "AddressURL": "www.mysite.com",
        "DisplayType": "True",
        "ImageURL": "service.png",
        "NotSplitBUser": "True",
        "ParentCategoryId": "3224",
        "PrivateUser": "True",
        "SortOrder": 0,
        "SplitBUser": "True",
        "TargetURL": "_self"
      },
      {
        "ID": "3298",
        "Name": "Call Us",
        "AddressURL": "www.mysite.com",
        "DisplayType": "True",
        "ImageURL": "service.png",
        "NotSplitBUser": "True",
        "ParentCategoryId": "3224",
        "PrivateUser": "True",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "SplitBUser": "True",
        "TargetURL": "_self"
      },
      {
        "ID": "3224",
        "Name": "Service",
        "AddressURL": "www.mysite.com",
        "DisplayType": "True",
        "ImageURL": "service.png",
        "NotSplitBUser": "True",
        "ParentCategoryId": "3224",
        "PrivateUser": "True",
        "SortOrder": 2,
        "SplitBUser": "True",
        "TargetURL": "_self"
      }
    ]
  },
  "responseCurrentBillState": null,
  "responseGetPcrfSubBuckets": null,
  "userData": {
    "abroadInd": null,
    "accountType": "B",
    "customerId": "",
    "fullName": "Juan",
    "subscriberNumber": ""
  }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to map those objects, I've created object called `RKSideMenu`, also an object called `RKUserData` they look like this:

```
@interface RKSideMenu : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *addressURL;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *displayType;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *id_number;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *imageURL;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL splitBUser;
+ (NSDictionary*)getAttributes;
@end

@implementation RKSideMenu
+ (NSDictionary*)getAttributes
{
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"addressURL", @"displayType", @"id_number", @"imageURL", @"name", @"splitBUser"]
                                       forKeys:@[@"AddressURL", @"DisplayType", @"ID", @"ImageURL", @"Name", @"SplitBUser"]];
}
@end

@interface RKUserData : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *abroadInd;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *accountType;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *customerID;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *fullName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *subscriberNumber;
+ (NSDictionary*)getAttributes;
@end

@implementation RKUserData
+ (NSDictionary*)getAttributes
{
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"abroadInd", @"accountType", @"customerID", @"fullName;", @"subscriberNumber"]
                                       forKeys:@[@"abroadInd", @"accountType", @"customerId", @"fullName;", @"subscriberNumber"]];
}
@end
```

I started mapping with those two methods, but than I stuck and don't know what to do. I look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping, but still couldn't get it right.

```
RKObjectMapping *sideMenuMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKSideMenu class]];
[sideMenuMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[RKSideMenu getAttributes]];

RKObjectMapping *userDataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKUserData class]];
[userDataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[RKUserData getAttributes]];
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Json on top replaced with real json from server.

Comment: Do you set a response descriptor somewhere?

Comment: I just don't know how to set `RKObjectMapping` and `RKResponseDescriptor` the right way.. that's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do in order to setup your mapping is first of all define the base url of your API, like so:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_TO_YOUR_API"]];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
```

Then you need to set a response descriptor for the url that outputs the json above:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:sideMenuMapping
                                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                               pathPattern:@"/mainScreenData"
                                                                                                   keyPath:@"displayMenuList.MenuList"
                                                                                               statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

"RKRequestMethodAny" should be replaced by the Request Method you are using e.g. "RKRequestMethodGET".

Then you just retrieve the objects by calling:

```
  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/mainScreenData"
                   parameters:nil
                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                          NSArray *sideMenuList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[mappingResult array]];
                      }
                      failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                          NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                      }];
```

I would highly recommend you having a look at the demos that are supplied by RestKit. That makes the whole process a lot clearer.

Cheers,
Sebastian

Comment: But the path is not /sideMenuList. The URL is `http://my.website.com/service/service.svc/screens/mainScreenData`, inside is the array that I posted on my question.

Comment: well then you need to change it accordingly. Set the base Url to whatever the base is. I would assume: http://my.website.com/service/service.svc and then set the path to /screens/mainScreenData

Comment: This is not my problem, I know how to do that. Have you read my question? my problem is how to map the object in the correct way...

Comment: @YossiTsafar, you have created mappings, Sebastian is showing you how to use them. If you still have problems you need to be more clear about what they are. You should show actual JSON, not some log output or similar. You need to list error messages you receive...

Comment: I've edited my question and added the JSON response from server, please check it out. I just don't know how's the right way to map those objects.. Thank you both.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of error you get, when you pull the objects with: [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath...

Comment: It says `The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: displayMenuList.MenuList`, what does it means?